# Is this is an ExpressionTrees bug? #3

Tags: c#, .net, expression-trees

Expressions class should be more accurate while searching for user-defined operators?

```
sealed class Foo
{
  // just the private static method!
  private static int op_Implicit() { return 1; }

  public static implicit operator int(Foo foo) { return 2; }
}

public class Program
{
  private static void Main()
  {
    var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Foo), "x");

    // IndexOutOfRangeException was unhandled!
    var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<Foo, int>>(
      Expression.Convert(param, typeof (int)), param);
  }
}
```

Also it's possible to define static `op_Explicit` or `op_Implicit` method with more than one arguments and Expression class accepts this method as an user-defined operator!

p.s. ExpressionTrees looking for operators with `BindingFlags.NonPublic` flag, it's allows to search operators in the user types, witch not directly visible for System.Core.dll, but it also allows the Expressions API to find private methods that "looks like" user-defined operators. But C# rules doesn't allows you to define and use non-public operators! I think the behavior of Expressions API should be the same...

Comment: *Why* do you believe that the expression tree library should follow the rules of C#, and not, say, VB?  Or some other language? Or no other language?  What justifies this belief?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Eric. Expression API behavior in this situations are not documented at all (I doesn't found any info about in the MSDN), and at the same time Expressions API are more frequently used for code generation tasks... So it would be nice, to have behavior that highly matches with the most popular .NET language behavior or API should be highly documented.

Comment: Also, the code above fails not because of "I belive", but because Expressions API operator search routine executes `method.GetParameters()[0].ParameterType` without any warranty that returned array is not empty or non one-element array.

Comment: I agree that the documentation could be better. And I also agree that the dereference exception is probably an expression tree bug. I'll pass it along to QA, but this will not be fixed for the v4 release of the library.

Comment: If you think that documentation is insufficeint, please either file a bug via Microsoft Connect or use the Feedback feature on MSDN online for a specific topic and decribe what you want to add to documentation. 
If you are looking for detailed documentation for Expression Trees, take a look at the http://dlr.codeplex.com/. The most advanced use cases are covered there, not on MSDN. Also you can communicate directly with the DLR team there.

Comment: declare your bug on the Microsoft Connect page ( https://connect.microsoft.com/dashboard/ ) for find a direct answer from MS